# EF 5.0 - Recommendation for the error "The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using `MVC4.0`, `EF 5.0` , `BLL` and `WCF` services architecture in our project. We have the project built using `MVC Areas` and we need the data models to be accessed for each new Area we create during development. In this scenario, there comes a requirement to use the same tables in more than one Data model for ex: we have a table for eg customer being used in two data models. In such cases -

We get a runtime error

> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type ‘Customer’.

After research we understand this is a known limitation of `EF` and there are two alternatives to resolve this

•Have data models in a different assemblies

•Rename the entities in the `EDMX` files

We expect a lot of `EDMX` files to be created based on the new `MVC Areas` in the future. Could you please recommend which one of the above options would be better and why? Is there any other alternate that we can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  Wouldn't that depend on your specific requirements?

Comment: What about one EDMX for everything? You can use it across areas.

Comment: It might be helpful if you were to explain a little more about how you intend to use the data in your application as that will make a difference to how best to implement this.

Comment: I know this sounds kinda lame, but the way I fixed this was adding an extra field with some random name. This caused my models to now be different and the error went away. Granted mine was with an anonymous type so I just added another field and just ignored it. Might be easier then changing the name to a substandard of your naming convention.

Comment: @glenatron the data is used specifically for each module. We have lot of modules that do specific functions but are also dependent on common entities like customer, order etc. If my reponse does not answer your question, can you please suggest couple of scenarios on what you are  looking for ?

Comment: @Tony how did that go? does it mean using this approach, we have to add new additional field every time we start a new module/area

Comment: In short, my anon model was clashing with the entity models so I just put an extra field on it so the model was definitely different from the one it was colliding with, it was basically just an extra public string ImAUselessField {get;set;}. Is this the best method? I am sure it is not but it prevented me from having to modify legacy code. I am not sure if you would have to do for each module area, just on whatever type it is complaining it cannot tell a difference from.